# Android Studio Not Showing The Vector Assets To Create

Tags: android, android-studio

As I'm Creating The Vector Asset Or Image Assets In Android Studio It Is Showing ME This.

And It Started After I Update The Android Studio And I Have Done Everything To Solve But It Is Not Going To Be Correct.

Comment: Please share a screenshot of it.

Comment: I Can't. Because When I'm Trying To Do It It is Showing Me To Gain Reputation Up to 10

Comment: Upload on google drive and share the link of it. I can't understand your issue clearly. Please explain exactly what you are facing.